# Ember network call payload behind one call

Tags: ember.js

I am sending a network call using ember.js

The event is triggered by a check box click that adds or removes an item from an array called features.

Currently if I click on the checkbox to add "edit users" to the array, the features array is updated and the update method in my account_owner model is triggered.

The users object is passed in to the update method and when I log user.features the array has all three items including the one that was just added.

before sending to the network I create a payload object that looks like:

> payload: { features: ["employee advocacy", "other", "edit_users"]}

Here is my update method

```
  update(user) {
      var payload = {
        features: user.features
      };
      console.log("@@@payload", payload)
      console.log("@@@this.accountID", this.accountID)
      const url = `/api/accounts/${this.id}/account_owners/${this.id}`;
      return put(url, payload).then(() => this);
    },
```

When this sends to the network only 2 of the three features are sent. 
the paylod looks like:

> payload: { features: ["employee advocacy", "other"]}

The thing is if I click the edit users check box again, edit_users is removed from the features array as well as the payload in the method when I log it but when the call is sent to the network all three items including edit_users show up in the payload. like this:

> payload: { features: ["employee advocacy", "other", "edit_users"]}

It seems like data in the network call is behind one click but I can not figure out why this is working this way.

Comment: have you tried to replace `features: user.features` by `features: [...user.features]`?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work

Comment: whats `put`? Have you tried to `Object.freeze` the payload?

Comment: Can you add your HBS code for the checkbox. I'm wondering if the native click event is getting sent as well as anything you have attached. Maybe resulting in calling your update function twice in quick succession or possibly leaving the UI in a reverse state.